# Service Bus / Request Forwarding

Tags: azure, servicebus

I'm doing some development with a third party that issues either a Get or POST to a public URL that I specify.

What I would like to do is set up a Relay service on the Azure Service Bus that my dev machine can listen to.  When the request comes in, I want to forward that request as if my web service was taking the request directly from the third party service.

When I'm ready, I'll deploy the application to a public service, change the URL that the third party service is sending too, and voila I should be up and running.

What I'm looking for looks exactly like this: [Clemens the Master of Service Bus](http://vasters.com/clemensv/PermaLink,guid,83edb04a-5696-401c-a919-8c1f379d130c.aspx) but it's from the 2009 CTP.  I'm working at it, but haven't yet got it working using all the new bits in 2012 (a.ka. its over my head at the moment).  Somebody want to help?

Clemens also help somebody else create a Reverse Proxy using the Service Bus, but I can't seem to find it.  Yes I've also tweeted Clemens, but I'm sure he is a busy man!

p.s. I know about Application Request Routing, but my dev machine is not on a public URL, I need to rewrite the URL after my client listener on the service bus recieves the message that was relayed from the Server side endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And from [Pedro Felix Blog](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/):...

http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/asp-net-web-api-creating-an-host-using-azure-service-bus/

I'm not sure I understand it all, and why it needs to be, but this is what I was asking for!

This means whenever and whereever I have an internet connection, I can develop an application where the host is issuing a webhook (like Github does).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your requirement exactly but can you not just use the OOTB Relay Service from the Service Bus
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/

Host your WCF RESTFul Service on-premises using Windows AppFabric Server that tunnels through the firewall and listen on the service bus endpoint. When your service is consumed it will host the relay end point in the Service Bus which will be relayed down to your on-premise service (where ever it is listening)?

The Windows Azure Training Kit has full samples on this?

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8396

Answer (score 0):

We're working on a solution to plug IIS into the Relay so that you can host any managed or unmanaged IIS site or service under a name in the SB namespace.

Until then, the most recent version of my reverse proxy has been integrated into a reverse proxy with rewriter by Nick Berardi here https://github.com/managedfusion/managedfusion-rewriter-proxy

Nick built this as a variant of his reverse proxy/re-writer here https://github.com/managedfusion/managedfusion-rewriter (that's also where you can find docs)

Comment: I was surprised when MVC4 came out, and the ability to recieve requests directly from the service bus was missing to an MVC4 app.  I wish I understood better why this is an issue, as it's a POST coming from a thrid-party app that is configured to POST to the ServiceBus, and my MVC application is behind a firewall, listening to the SB.  POST in should be relayed out as another POST without having to marshal across protocols.  What am I missing?